# Complete metric but not uniformly locally compact on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it possible to give a **complete metric** over the real line **R**, which is compatible with the Euclidean topology, but not uniformly locally compact?

**Definition**: A metric space (X,d) is **uniformly locally compact** if there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that the closure of the open ball $B_d(x,\varepsilon)$ is compact for every $x\in X$.

Comment: What does "uniformly locally compact" mean?

Comment: Dear David, I have change my edit to give the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose an injection $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ whose image is uniformly discrete, so $(n,m)\neq (n',m')$ implies $|f(n,m)-f(n',m')|>\delta.$ Define a metric on $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ by

$$d_{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}((n,m),(n',m'))=\begin{cases}
\infty&\text{ if $n\neq n',$}\\
1/n&\text{ if $n=n'$ but $m\neq m',$}\\
0&\text{ if $n=n'$ and $m=m'.$}
\end{cases}$$

Then take $d$ to be the largest metric on $\mathbb R$ satisfying $d(x,y)\leq |x-y|$ and $d(f(n,m),f(n',m'))\leq d_{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}((n,m),(n',m')).$ In other words, it's the path metric where there are edges between $x$ and $y$ of length $|x-y|,$ and also edges between $f(n,m)$ and $f(n,m')$ of length $1/n$ for $m\neq m',$ and the distance between two points is the infimum of the total length of edges, taken over finite paths joining those points.

We need to check that $d(x,y)>0$ for $x\neq y.$ Any path from $x$ to $y$ of length less than $\delta/2$ either goes through points $x',y'$ in the image of $f$ with $d(x,x')<\delta/2$ and $d(y',y)<\delta/2,$ or it does not go through any points in the image of $f.$ In the latter case the path has length at least $|x-y|.$ In the former case there is a unique choice of $x'$ and $y',$ and the path has length at least $d(x,x')+d(x',y')+d(y',y),$ which is positive unless $x=y.$

I claim that the metric is complete. Any Cauchy sequence eventually lies in some $\delta/2$-ball. The distance between $f(n,m)$ and $f(n',m')$ for $n\neq n'$ is at least $\delta.$ So there is at most one $n$ such that this ball contains points of the form $f(n,m).$ So any distances less than $1/n$ are ordinary Euclidean distances, and the Cauchy sequence converges in the usual metric.

But it's not uniformly locally compact, because for each $n$ the ball $B_d(f(n,m),2/n)$ contains the infinite discrete set $\{f(n,m)\mid m\in\mathbb N\}.$

Comment: Is it complete?

Comment: What if $x=0$ or $y=0$? usual distance as the max term becomes "infinity"?

Comment: @ASM: yes, in fact it is locally isometric to the usual metric

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: yes, $1/0=\infty$

Comment: @Dap Please Dap, can you be more specific in your proof? I d'ont see that it is a metric or that it is complete, even if it is locally isometric. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @ASM: sorry, I don't think that was right. I've written up a different argument now.

Comment: @Dap I think it works. I'm just checking.

Comment: @Dap I propose the following simplication. Let $\{P_k:k\in \mathbb N\}$ a partition of $\mathbb N$ such that $|P_k|=\omega _0$ for every $k\in \mathbb N $. Then define $L(x,y)=1/k$ if $x,y\in P_k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$ and $L(x,y)=|x-y|$ otherwise. Then, put $$d(x,y)=inf \{\sum_{i=1}^{m} L(u_{i-1}, u_i): u_0=x, u_m=y, u_i\in \mathbb R, i=1,...,m-1, m\in \mathbb N\}$$